# Making a function with mutually exclusive pre defined argument list

Tags: excel, vba

I know what an optional argument list is and how to set default vales.

```
Public Function argTest(arg1 As String, Optional arg2 As String = "TEST", Optional arg3 As String = "TEST") As Long
'Some logic and stuff
End Function
```

But thats not exactly what I'm after.  Here is an example

If you add the UIAutomationClient reference and paste the following code into a sub

```
Dim uiElement As IUIAutomationElement
Dim uiProp As IUIAutomationCondition
    
uiElement.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, uiProp) = 0
```

Where you define the TreeScope_Children is the functionality I'm after.  right after typing "uiElement.FindFirst(" you get a drop down menu of options.

How do I make a function call do THAT?

Comment: Using an [`Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement).

Answer (score 3):

Using an enumeration:

```
Enum Foo
   bar = 1
   baz = 2
End Enum

Public Function argTest(grr As Foo)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a method parameter which references an *existing* enum from a library referenced by your VBA project, you can do it like this:

[image]